# Trouble with Turning Off/Powering Off two systems at once, how should I approach this?

Tags: batteries, wire, peltier

I have an overall that I want to shut off completely with a flick of a switch; however, the system I want to shut off is comprised of two smaller, completely separate systems.

Let me give you an example,

[image]

If you can see, the two smaller systems are completely separate; however, I want to be able to flick a switch and have the entire system turn off (both peltier-battery combinations). **Basically, how can I connect the two systems without getting into the messy territory of parallel batteries**.

**In addition, I also want to add a thermostat control that controls the entire system's Peltiers (both of them in sync, together), so I need a way to link the two smaller systems together to have it under control of one thermostat controller.**

Thanks Guys

Comment: 2- or 4-position switch?

Comment: Use a Double-Pole-Single-Throw switch (DPST) http://www.dummies.com/programming/electronics/components/switches-in-electronic-circuits-poles-and-throws/ https://www.amazon.com/Gardner-Bender-GSW-14-Toggle-Switch/dp/B00004WLK9

Comment: I would carefully select a suitable relay.

Answer (score 2):

You are making this over complicated by keeping the batteries separate.

Pick a side and combine them. perhaps the negative side as I have shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frMjGc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or topside like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKNxg7.png)</sup>

Alternative is to use a dual pole relay powered by one of the batteries, but remember the relay will drain that battery faster.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8KyKl.png)</sup>

Comment: Hey Trevor, I am a novice still and am having a hard time reading the diagram. I am not interested in using a relay, as I have no experience with them, and it is looking very likely that I will combine the batteries in parallel. The only thing I am worried about is a USB cable not being able to transfer 4.8A of power, but I believe I can make it work. **What do you mean by pick the negative side, don't I have to combine both negative and positive or are you saying something different?** And can you explain the workings of the top diagram to me a little more? Thanks, you're the best!

Comment: @OmarSumadi no, if you want to keep the power sources separate you can still combine either the positive or the negative sides through a switch. You need diodes though to prevent back driving through the peltiers or the fan or whatever. Not sure how I can make that drawing any simpler.